# R resources in non-English languages

Tags: r, references

Through a project I am now working on (which I won't link to so to not have this an ad question), I came to realize how difficult it is to find R resources, not in English.

Thus my question is - what resources do you know of, recommend, for learning R in non-English languages?  (tutorials, blogs, wiki's, forums, and so on)

Comment: Which other languages are you interested in?

Comment: Dear chl - any of them.  My real motivation is to find bloggers in other languages, but I would feel fine with other websites from which to find bloggers (see more about my motivation here:  http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-bloggers-now-in-your-language/)

Comment: The only French blogger I know is writing in... English (and isn't very productive anymore :) http://zoonek.free.fr/

Comment: Dear chl, I actually got his permission some time ago to add him to R-bloggers.  I do hope he'll go back to writing one day.  Thanks for the pointers so far.

Comment: I hear Japanese R community is pretty large. Too bad we don't communicate (much).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In german:

- [A short introduction to R](http://www.wiwi.uni-bielefeld.de/%7Ewolf/skripten/Rkurs.pdf) very short, covers only the basics of R programming
- http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/GNU_R teaches the basics of R programmming in detail and also contains some examples of producing graphics and statistics.
- [cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Sawitzki-Einfuehrung.pdf](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Sawitzki-Einfuehrung.pdf) a lengthy introduction into statistics with R with a smaller focus on programming.

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't appear to be much in Russian, but here is a couple of links:

- http://herba.msu.ru/shipunov/software/r/r-ru.htm contains pointers to a number of Russian-language R resources;
- http://voliadis.ru/taxonomy/term/18 is a blog with some R content.

Comment: Wonderful link to that blogger - thank you aix !

Answer (score 4):

Some german blog entries:
http://www.schockwellenreiter.de/blog/tag/r/
and
http://markheckmann.wordpress.com/category/r-r-code/

edit: and one more:
http://wagezudenken.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 3):

All RSS feeds I follow are in English actually, so I'll just point to tutorials available in French, or made by French researchers.

Apart from the [Contributed Documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html) on CRAN, I often browse the R website hosted at the [bioinformatics lab](http://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/R/enseignement.html) in Lyon (France); it is mostly in French, but it also includes english material. I also like [Philippe Besse](http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~besse/enseignement.html) resources (SAS + R).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a german blog with some posts on R:
http://blog.berndweiss.net/tag/r/

Recently started, with no posts on R yet, but focused on open data, is this blog:
http://blog.zeit.de/open-data

Answer (score 1):

See the bottom 2 thirds of http://cran.fhcrc.org/other-docs.html (or other cran site).